# AngularJS validation - email switch and email field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two fields in my application - One for *emaiSwitch* which consists of "*Yes*, *No*" values and another field for entering users *emailId*.

I need to disable *emailId* text field when the *emaiSwitch* value is No and enable it when its value is 'Yes' which i did using

`if($scope.email.newValue === 'N') return true` which goes to `ng-disabled` directive.

The problem I am facing is with email pattern. When emailSwitch value is 'Y', and I enter invalid email id there will be validation error. Then, when i change emailSwitch value to 'N', then earlier displayed validation error is not going away though field is disabled.

here is my code

**HTML**

```
<select class="select"
        id={{emailSwitch.fieldName}}
        name={{emailSwitch.fieldName}}
        model="emailSwitch.newValue"
        options="emailSwitch.optionsList"
        aria-live="polite"
        role="search"
        value-attr="value"
        labelAttr="label"
        disable="emailSwitch.disabled == 'true'">
</select>
<input type='text'
       ng-pattern=emailId.pattern
       id={{emailId.fieldName}}
       ng-model='emailId.newValue'
       minlength={{emailId.minlength}}
       ng-minlength={{emailId.minlength}}
       maxlength={{emailId.maxlength}}
       ng-required= {{emailId.required}}
       ng-maxlength={{emailId.maxlength}}
       ng-disabled="emailId.disableEmail()"
/>
```

Javascript

```
emailId = {};
emailId.displayName = 'Email Address';
emailId.fieldName = 'emailAddress';
emailId.minlength = 1;
emailId.maxlength = 250;
emailId.required = 'true';
emailId.pattern = Service.emailPattern();
emailId.patternError = $scope.EmailInvalid;
emailId.disableEmail = function () {
var emailSwitch =  emailSwitch.newValue;
if(emailSwitch === 'N')
{
    emailId.minlength = 0;
    emailId.maxlength = 0;
    emailId.required = 'false';
    return true;
}
else
{
    emailId.minlength = 1;
    emailId.maxlength = 250;
    emailId.required = 'true';
    return false;
}
};
```

**Edit:**

After some analysis, I understand that emailId.required = 'true' which was set initially is setting the required 'true'. Conditions below is setting ng-required 'true'/'false', however, required attribute still holds "required". It seems that ng-required is not dynamically setting this html attribute 'required'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. ng-required is getting false/true as String and is not dynamically setting HTMLs required attribute. removing {{}} brackets (or '' in above example) has given ng-required = true which has set the HTMLs required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

could you just clear the email value when the emailSwitch.newValue == 'N'? If you really want to save the value they entered just set the pattern to an empty string.

Comment: Keeping email pattern as empty string is giving issue in emailSwitch drop down. Unable to select anything.. 
emailId.pattern = ' ';

Answer (score 0):

When binding data ng-pattern accepts Sting type value (Example: ng-pattern='emailId.pattern')
While setting value from controller you have set proper value type like string, number...
nim amd max value should be String type value and required is boolean value but you are stting String type value

For More information https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Below is modified code

```js
emailId = {};
emailId.displayName = 'Email Address';
emailId.fieldName = 'emailAddress';
emailId.minlength = '1';
emailId.maxlength = '250';
emailId.required = true;
emailId.pattern = Service.emailPattern();
emailId.patternError = $scope.EmailInvalid;
emailId.disableEmail = function() {
  var emailSwitch = emailSwitch.newValue;
  if (emailSwitch === 'N') {
    emailId.minlength = '0';
    emailId.maxlength = '0';
    emailId.required = false;
    return true;
  } else {
    emailId.minlength = '1';
    emailId.maxlength = '250';
    emailId.required = true;
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<select class="select"
        id='emailSwitch.fieldName'
        name='emailSwitch.fieldName'
        model="emailSwitch.newValue"
        options="emailSwitch.optionsList"
        aria-live="polite"
        role="search"
        value-attr="value"
        labelAttr="label"
        disable="emailSwitch.disabled == 'true'">
</select>
<input type='text'
       ng-pattern='emailId.pattern'
       id='emailId.displayName'
       ng-model='emailId.newValue'
       minlength='emailId.minlength'
       ng-minlength='emailId.minlength'
       maxlength='emailId.maxlength'
       ng-required= 'emailId.required'
       ng-maxlength='emailId.maxlength'
       ng-disabled="emailId.disableEmail()"
/>
```

Comment: Its working without '' for pattern. My issue is unable to clear the validation when field gets disabled..

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet in jsfiddle or somewhere i can execute code snippet.

Comment: I will provide one. My problem is ng-required is not setting html required attribute dynamically. i.e. when i set emailId.required as false it is not removing required attribute